# change the width of linear layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having this xml layout for a list view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/menu"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#2f4f4f" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2f4f4f" android:cacheColorHint="#2f4f4f" android:scrollbars="none">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The linear layout occupies the full screen width by default.

[image]

I want to change it programatically.I want to make something like this :

[image]

But when I change width of linearlayout nothing happens,it still occupies full screen width

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
 View menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_layout, null);
 menu.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

after hardcoding layout width in list view as  :

```
 <ListView
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#2f4f4f"
  android:cacheColorHint="#2f4f4f"
  android:scrollbars="none" >

</ListView>
```

I get this :

[image]

Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make changes in listview like shown below, **do hard code for layout width in XML.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@android:color/white">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2f4f4f"   >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

you were doing **Wrap_content in linear layout** and in **listview fill_parent**, therefore linearlayout which is wrapping listview i.e. full screen.

Comment: after hardcoding  layout width I get something different,see my edited question.Also I want to change the width of menu based on a preference,so I have to do it programatically.

Comment: change your linear layout background color to white

Comment: Thanks for your help.changing the background gives the expected result,but the width of linear layout is still full screen width.what I am doing is adding the layout to a horizontal scroll view and I want the menu width to be user configurable.So my problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like it to fit multiple screen sizes I'd suggest adding an empty layout and using weights.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@android:color/white">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#2f4f4f"   >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@android:color/white">

</LinearLayout>
```

I just eyeballed the weights. Adjust them to the width that you need. If you do it this way then you won't have to hard code the size for every screen size.